# How to handle if statement comparing existing file using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a function with if statement. I want to check all the existency of a folder and file then do something.

I tried this code, I used `-and` , but it only check the the first folder, if the first folder not exist, it will do the next process, it doesn't check one by one the folder and file, then do the next process.

```
Function Call
{
& .\run.cmd
start-Sleep -s 1 
$Log = Get-Content .\log.txt | Where-Object {$_.Contains("111")}

if(
    ($Log) -and 
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FilePath\AGM")) -and 
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FilePath\GM\JOB")) -and
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FilePath\GM\PO")) -and
    (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FilePath\GM\GM.flg"))
){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM"
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM\JOB"
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM\PO"
        New-Item -ItemType File -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM\GM.flg"

    CHK_STAGE

} 
else 
{
    END
}
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is operating exactly as designed. You have a single `if` statement, with several clauses, connected with `-and` which means that *all of them must be `$true`* to satisfy the condition and enter the block.

What you seem to want really, is four separate `if` statements, each of which evaluates *one* condition and then acts on the result of that.

```
if($Log) {
    if (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FilePath\AGM")) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM"
    }

    if (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FilePath\GM\JOB")) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM\JOB"
    }

    if (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FilePath\GM\PO")) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM\PO"
    }

    if (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists("$FilePath\GM\GM.flg")) {
        New-Item -ItemType File -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM\GM.flg"
    }
}
```

But I'll also point out that when it comes to creating directories, your `if` statements are redundant.

You can just do this:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM\JOB"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$FilePath\GM\PO"
```

And the call will succeed whether the directories already existed or not. It will also return each directory.

For the file call, it would zero out the file if it already existed, so you could remove `-Force` and then use `-ErrorAction Ignore` or `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` (the latter still populated `$Error` while the former doesn't; both succeed with no messages or interruption).

```
New-Item -ItemType File -Path "$FilePath\GM\GM.flg" -ErrorAction Ignore
```